# Visual Studio 2010: What is a .pfk file?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I recently found out about Visual Studio's ability to create a Setup.exe file for your project when you publish the project (Build -> Publish [Project Name]).  When I've done this I noticed a new file being added to my project with the name "[Project Name]_TemporaryKey.pfk" (so if the project was HelloWorld the .pfk would be "HelloWorld_TemporaryKey.pfk").

What is this file and why do I need it?

Do I need a "PermanentKey" at some point?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .pfk file is Personal Information Exchange file that is used to "sign" your Visual Studio assemblies.

> Assembly signing (also called strong-name signing) gives an application or component a unique identity that other software can use to identify and refer explicitly to it. A strong name consists of its simple text name, version number, culture information (if provided), plus a public/private key pair. This information is stored in a key file; this can be a **Personal Information Exchange (PFX) file** or a certificate from the current user's Windows certificate store. More information can be obtained [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

I haven't worked with them much but I believe the link(s) below may shed some light on their use:

[The Use of .PFK and .SNK files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e9ef6858-e82c-4326-a962-53efbc010a01)

[Signing an Assembly - MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Hope these helped.